# firstOrCreate in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am either adding to my table or editing an existing row.

I've looked into firstOrCreate but I can't seem to get it to work, it always creates a new row.

```
return $this->firstOrCreate(array('id' => $input['id'], 'title' => $input['title'], 'sell' => $input['sell'], 'article' => $input['article'], 'thumb' => $input['thumb'], 'gallery' => $input['galleryData'], 'date' => $input['date'], 'published' => $input['published']));
```

Things like title change when the user edits them, is there a way to search the table based on the id, if it exists then update, if not, then create?

Answer (score 2):

If the title changes, then using this method is illogical. The method you mention check for an item with ALL the given specifications.

What you should be doing instead:

```
// find the item, given the ID
$item = Item::firstOrNew(array('id' => $input['id']));

// add the fields from your input
$item->title = $input['title'];
$item->sell  = $input['sell'];
$item->article = $input['article'];
$item->thumb = $input['thumb'];
$item->gallery = $input['galleryData'];
$item->date = $input['date'];
$item->published = $input['published'];

// Save the thing
$item->save();
```